# How to use more than one openGL state in an application?

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, dll

I am aware openGL is a state machine, what I'm not aware of is how the state is stored.

I have a project where I have to render things off-screen to memory in a c++ dll/dynamic-library and pass the final image to a c# application that also uses openGL state to do any imaginable thing with(render whatever the application wants in whichever fashion). This obviously makes it impossible to separate what openGL state is being used to draw off-screen(in the dll/dynamic-library) and what openGL state is being used to draw in the application.

How would I go about creating/using a separate openGL state for my off-screen renderer in c++? Would c++ std::threads use/create a separate openGL state when using openGL in them?

And finally(I dont need this last part answered, but to be complete), is there a way to handle more than one openGL state in a single application(and alternate between these states) without the use of multiple threads?

Comment: I think you are conflating two different meanings of _state_.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Im asking if I have to use threads if I want to use openGL in two separate instances. I believe for openGL the actual term is "context" instead of state you are right I guess.

Comment: I was just commenting on the statement that "openGL is a state machine". Any program is a state machine. But the library itself probably isn't well described as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the final render image to another application , you can pass it using PBO and the pointer to the pixel data using glMapBuffer.

This is the code where i am passing the pixel data to other application.

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
writeIndex = (writeIndex + 1) % 2;
readIndex = (readIndex + 1) % 2;
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[writeIndex]);
                    // copy from framebuffer to PBO asynchronously. it will be ready in the NEXT frame
glReadPixels(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
                    // now read other PBO which should be already in CPU memory
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo[readIndex]);
unsigned char* downsampleData = (unsigned char *)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
float Time1 = bm.GetTime();
blueOut.RenderOut(downsampleData, FieldNumber); // Pass it to the other application
                
glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

you have to write drivers for the c# application which will pass the data pointer to the application in realtime.

Comment: Im currently passing the image to ram and then copying it to another image and finally passing it back to the gpu; how slow is this? would it work relatively quick if it were the only bottleneck? is this approach the same/similar?

Comment: @MatiasChara Generally DMA is preferred for such transfers , i am doing a DMA which is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's much like context switch for CPU to do thread schedule.

Say you have two pipeline M and N in a single thread and M runs first, when you want to switch to N, you can save M's context first and then start a N's pipeline and at some point when N's running you could save N's context and restore M's context. So the question is how to save OpenGL's context explicitly.

Actually OpenGL supply many query/get methods(or several methods but many parameters) like `glGetIntegerv`, `glGetVertexAttribiv` and `glGetVertexAttribPointerv`([glGet](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml)), you can query the and save the result to somewhere and restore them at some point.

Here's a simple wrapper class example:

```
class GLStateSaver {
    GLuint framebuffer;
    GLint activeTexture;
    GLint boundedTextures[MAX_USED_TEXTURES];
    // ... add more fields if you need, like programID, memory object id etc.
public:
    void Save() {
        glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &framebuffer);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE, &activeTexture);
        // ...
    }
    void Restore() {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
        glActiveTexture(activeTexture);
        // ...
    }
}
```